# how to lower current volume when three audio files are playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three audio clips that I want the user to compare each of the sounds when clicked on. That works great but when I am sliding the volume it starts to play the other sounds as well. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<audio id="au1"><source src="assets/audio/HD.wav" ></audio>         
<audio id="au2"><source src="assets/audio/Digital.wav" ></audio>
<audio id="au3"><source src="assets/audio/Analog.wav"></audio>

 <div class="audioSlider">
    <img src="assets/img/speaker_icon.png"/>
    <input id="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" type="range"/>
 </div>


<script>
 var au1 = document.getElementById('au1');
 var au2 = document.getElementById('au2');
 var au3 = document.getElementById('au3');

 au1.volume = 1;
 au2.volume = 0;
 au3.volume = 0;
 au1.play();
 au2.play();
 au3.play();

 $("#HD").click(function() {
   au1.volume = 1;
   au2.volume = 0;
   au3.volume = 0;

   if(au2.volume && au3.volume === 0){
      $('#volume').on("change", function() {
       var volume = document.getElementById("volume");
       au1.volume = volume.value;
      });
    }
 });
 $("#Digital").click(function() {
   au1.volume = 0;
   au2.volume = 1;
   au3.volume = 0;

   if(au1.volume && au3.volume === 0){
     $('#volume').on("change", function() {
       var volume = document.getElementById("volume");
       au2.volume = volume.value;
      });
    }
 });  

 $("#Analog").click(function() {
    au1.volume = 0;
    au2.volume = 0;
    au3.volume = 1;

    if(au1.volume && au2.volume === 0){
       $('#volume').on("change", function() {
          var volume = document.getElementById("volume");
          au3.volume = volume.value;
        });
     }
   }); 
</script>
```

Comment: just pause the audio using jquery.

Comment: au1.pause(); au2.pause(); au3.play();

Comment: I cant pause because whenever the user wants to compare sound1 with sound3 or sound2 they are all in unison and have different effects over them. I mute all sounds just fine but when I modify the volume I get the other sounds playing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that all your event handlers for the slider are firing. You can verify this by adding console.log statements.

I think your logic is off.

Try changing your event handlers like so:

```
   $('#volume').on("change", function() {
     if(0 === au2.volume && 0 === au3.volume){
       var volume = document.getElementById("volume");
       au1.volume = volume.value;
     }
    })
```

And similarly for #Analog and #Digital.